# SQL vs MySQL vs. SMSS vs. RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms, rdbms

I am starting into studying SQL and am having trouble understanding the relationships between the various components.

To my understanding, SQL is a langauge (akin to PHP, JS, etc.) which is used to interact with databases.

MySQL seems to be a specific software, a specific RDBMS, but how exactly does it relate with SQL and SSMS? Is it the thing that actually stores the data, or does it simply manage them by interpreting SQL commands? I'm mostly confused on what the SSMS does then.

Any help or tips on such subjects would be appreciated, though I understand if this topic is not specific enough and needs to be removed.

Comment: SQL - language/ MySQL,SQL Server, Oracle DB, PostgreSQL is a database system(server side) RDBMS/ SSMS is a client tool

Comment: please recognize that SQL is not a language like you would think of an object-oriented language or procedural language. In many ways the ANSI SQL standard is more like a protocol or a series of *generally accepted statements* based on mathematical principles of set theory, predicate logic and relational algebra. [**Read More**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334289/why-is-sql-the-only-database-query-language)

Comment: @Martin that was very helpful, helped clear up what SQL is, thank you; it's not a language so much as a ruleset that many similar languages are based on.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda What do you mean SSMS is a client tool? If I'm developing a website, users do not have to download SSMS just to load my webpage.

Comment: @Seraphendipity SSMS is development client tool, IDE like Visual Studio, Eclipse or Netbeans

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Ah, I see. When you say "like Visual Studio, Eclipse...", are you making an analogy that they're both dev tools, or are you saying that I can use my preferred IDE to do the same thing SSMS?

Comment: **MySQL** is a RDBMS (a database engine). MySQL implements the **SQL language** so any client app can execute SQL on it to save and retrieve data. **SSMS** is an IDE/tool you use that *can act* as a client app to run SQL into MySQL.